# Wistia: Open modal via specific url without playing

Tags: javascript, wistia

On our home page, we have a Wistia embed that opens in a modal and plays when the user clicks a text link. I'd like to create a special URL that I can send people to that will automatically open the modal but NOT start playing.

Html:

```
<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_i74bcbgfkm popover=true popoverAnimateThumbnail=true popoverContent=link wistia_embed_initialized" style="display:inline" id="wistia-i74bcbgfkm-1">
  <div id="wistia_36.thumb_container" class="wistia_click_to_play" style="position: relative; display: inline;">
    <a class="text-link" href="#">See the science. Watch video.</a>
  </div>
</span>
```

JS:

```
// Auto Play Wistia Video via Specific Link

$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#science') != -1) {
    ## open modal?
  }

});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: may ask the guys at http://wistia.com ?

Comment: hey, thanks - I linked them to this post

Answer (score 1):

Just stumble upon the same issue and here's how I fixed it:

⚠️ Be careful about always using the same ID of your Wistia video.

```
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/m1h6asljqh.jsonp"></script>
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_m1h6asljqh popover=true popoverContent=link" style="display:inline">
  <a href="#" class="">What is Marker.io?</a>
</span>

<script>
    window._wq = window._wq || [];

    _wq.push({ id: "m1h6asljqh", onReady: function(video) {

      var video = Wistia.api("m1h6asljqh");

      if(window.location.href.indexOf('#showvideo') != -1) {
        video.popover.show(); // open the popover
        video.play(); // play the video
      }
    }});
</script>
```

Let me know if it helped!

Cheers